# Configural frequency analysis

Tags: sample, definition

What do you think about configural frequency analysis?

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configural_frequency_analysis

I personally love the idea to extract types and antitypes in heterogenous samples in an explorative approach. In Germany, however, this statistical procedure seems baraly taught in University context.

Why is this technique not common? Are there practical reasons ( e.g. no need) or is the technique out-dated or suffers from other problems?

Comment: (+1) Although I am unfamiliar with CFA,a  quick reading of your reference suggests to me that (in the binomial setting, at least) it is a simple way to evaluate the residuals in a two-way table and as such is naturally subsumed within standard elementary statistical procedures.

Comment: It can also be used for categorial variables over binomial settings, e.g. comparing different school grades. 

Further information here: http://www.stat.tugraz.at/AJS/ausg082/082vonEye.pdf

If you want to test it, you can use this freeware program (which is slightly outdated, but still works under Win7):
http://www.dgps.de/fachgruppen/methoden/mpr-online/issue14/art1/article.html

Comment: Thank you: that confirms my characterization of the procedure. A more sophisticated way of explaining it is that a model of the two-way (or even multi-way) data is adopted and outlying residuals from the model are identified as "types" (when they are large and positive) or "antitypes" (when they are large and negative). This general description actually goes way beyond what CFA does, because--while maintaining the same objectives--it opens the analysis to the more general and robust techniques of exploratory data analysis that have been developed in the 45 years since CFA was invented.

Comment: Thanks for your response: regarding the characterizarion of the procedure as residual analysis, feel free to check the first passage of the discussion in this paper: http://www.pabst-publishers.de/psychology-science/1-2004/ps_1_2004_150-170.pdf - what do you think?

Comment: Thank you for sharing that; I am glad to be enlightened. In rejoinder I would first admit that CFA, as an exploratory tool, has objectives that might differ from other uses of models of multi-way data. However, my characterization was not made from the point of view of any particular model--and that generality renders most of von Eye's defense moot. What it seems to come down to is that CFA *is* an analysis of residuals having a particular aim. We should therefore be comparing it to other exploratory methods having similar aims, while noting its methods are conventional and in general use.

Comment: @whuber Very nice response, thanks. Which more general and robust techniques of exploratory data analysis would you mention as possible alternatives?

Comment: See chapters on making two-way and multi-way analyses in Tukey's [*EDA*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Exploratory_Data_Analysis.html?id=Fz5DnwEACAAJ).